# How to navigate through md-list-item on arrow keypress?

Tags: html, angular2-forms, wai-aria

Is there a way to use the arrow key to navigate through the list items below. Tab works just fine due to the tabindex but arrow does not. Any suggestion with example would be great.

```
<md-list-item>
    <md-list-item id="tab1">
        <a tabindex = "1" routerLink="/link1">{{val1}}</a>
</md-list-item>
</md-list-item>
    <md-list-item id="tab2">
        <a tabindex = "2" routerLink="/link2">{{val2}}</a>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list-item>
<md-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is. I do not know if you are looking for code or guidance on how it should work, so I will just answer guidance.

The WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1 describe how to build a menu that operates as an OS-level system menu would work. While I don't know if you want to implement the roles here (because that will tell screen reader users that it should function like a menu in their OS), you can use it as guidance on what interactions you can support.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried and it works in jquery. Yet I need only in Angular 2 as asked not to mix jquery and A2. Need to know how to treat keypress events on md list

Comment: Ah. Then I am out. My Angular knowledge is poor.